# Browser redirection

Tags: browser, redirect

I am always getting redirecting to this 
http://search.tedata.net
tedata is my internet provider . I called them they say they can't help unless I have windows but I don't want to go back to windows 
I tried rootkit hunter but it didn't work either

I don't know what is wrong , how could this keep coming up even after formatting my hard ? is it possible that the ubuntu  version I have downloaded from the website is defective , the problem didn't appear with linux mint or xubuntu 
it only appeared when I replaced unity with cinnamon but now it appears right away after clean installation of ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Did they give you a modem, router, or some kind of box connected by ethernet cable?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe their dns redirects your requests to their website for some particular pages.
Try changing your dns settings to some other server (for instance try to set the Google public dns servers in the network connection properties, the ips are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)

Answer (score 0):

When my modem is messed I get redirected back to my ISP website.  One thing to do would be to try connecting to the internet through another computer and see if it still redirects you.  Also you could try another browser and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rectify via setting your own DNS settings:

Go to the network manager and right-click it:

[image]

and go to Edit Connections. On either the Wired, Wireless, or Mobile broadband, there should be a connection already established. Click it and click Edit.

Give these settings on the IPv4 Settings tab:

[image]

and try disconnecting and reconnection. If that still fails, it's time for some ore drastic measures that usually aren't needed.

Repeat the steps, but under IPv4 settings, use these settings(a bit different, with more info)

[image]